# change X ticks in matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I plotted a graph in matplotlib, and it looks like this : [image: graph]

On the x-axis are values **[50,100,150,200,250]**. I want to change them to **[10,20,30,40,50]**. But without changing or touching graph. I dont want use `plt.xlim()` because it changes only part of the displaying graph. How can I do this?

My plotting code:

```
def plot_random_angular():
    m = np.loadtxt('angle.txt')
    uhol = m[:,6]
    vys = []
    for x in xrange(1,len(uhol)):
        vys.append((uhol[x] - uhol[x-1])*4)
    x=np.linspace(0,len(vys),len(vys))
    plt.ylim(-5,5)
    plt.xlim(0,250)
    plt.grid()
    plt.xlabel('time [s]',fontsize = 18)
    plt.ylabel('angle [deg]',fontsize = 18)
    plt.plot(x,vys,'black')
    return vys
```

Comment: Can you post the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make everything 1/5 of the original?:

```
ax=plt.gca() 
#ax.get_xticks() will get the current ticks
ax.set_xticklabels(map(str, ax.get_xticks()/5.0))
```